# Android - Bluetooth - Limit Scan range

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am currently making an Android utility related to Bluetooth, and I need to change the device discovery range of my device..

Is there a way for me to do so? I am currently looking into using the TPL to do this, but I am not so sure..

Either an Android application or changes in the kernel are possible.

Thank you very much.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be on the right track. To reduce the range you would need to reduce the Tx power while searching and this should be possible through the HCI command hci_write_inquiry_transmit_power_level (external/bluetooth/bluez/lib/bluetooth/hci_lib.h)

You need to figure out how this is done in Bluez (if it is being used) and then extend it to use in your application.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I wanted to try this, but the most that I found out is that Android seems to be using dbus to use Bluez, but I got lost tracing dbus->Bluez->hci.. haha...
I'm not that much of an expert on both Android and bluetooth... do you have any references that I might use? thanks.. :D

Comment: Try looking into hciconfig.c and the files in tools folder. This builds a hciconfig executable which you should be able to use to understand how this works.